# CKEditor5 with React: Adding a custom plugin fails (dublicated modules)

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react, ckeditor5-plugin

I'm trying to build a custom plugin to CKEditor5 in a react application. I've mainly followed these 2 tutorials:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/react.html
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/plugins/creating-simple-plugin-timestamp.html

Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';

class Timestamp extends Plugin {
  init() {
    console.log( 'Timestamp was initialized.' );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
      <CKEditor
        editor={ ClassicEditor }
        config={ {
          plugins: [ Timestamp ],
          toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic' ]
        } }
        data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
        onReady={ (editor: any) => {
          // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
          console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
        } }
        onChange={ ( event: any, editor: { getData: () => any; } ) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          console.log( { event, editor, data } );
        } }
        onBlur={ ( event: any, editor: any ) => {
          console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
        } }
        onFocus={ ( event: any, editor: any ) => {
          console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
        } }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I keep getting a white screen and this error in the console though:

```
Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    at ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/version.js (version.js:144:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/emittermixin.js (ckeditorerror.js:195:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/observablemixin.js (mix.js:48:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

The documentation on the error code (duplicated modules) doesn't tell anything about custom plugins (only imported plugins). From what I can see here (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/using-react-in-a-widget.html) it should be doable.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I should've read the documentation more carefully.. essentially you have to update your webpack configs if you're working in a repo generated from create-react-app. There is a thorough guide here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/react.html#using-create-react-app3

Here's what my `rules` block looks like in my `./config/webpack.config.js` file:

```
rules: [
        // Handle node_modules packages that contain sourcemaps
        shouldUseSourceMap && {
          enforce: 'pre',
          exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|css)$/,
          loader: require.resolve('source-map-loader'),
        },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // TODO: Merge this config once `image/avif` is in the mime-db
            // https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db
            {
              test: [/\.avif$/],
              type: 'asset',
              mimetype: 'image/avif',
              parser: {
                dataUrlCondition: {
                  maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                },
              },
            },
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              type: 'asset',
              parser: {
                dataUrlCondition: {
                  maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.svg$/,
              // Exclude `js` files to keep the "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through the "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpack's internal loaders.
              exclude: [
                /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                /\.html$/,
                /\.json$/,
                /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
                /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/
              ],
              use: [
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack'),
                  options: {
                    prettier: false,
                    svgo: false,
                    svgoConfig: {
                      plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
                    },
                    titleProp: true,
                    ref: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                  options: {
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash].[ext]',
                  },
                },
              ],
              issuer: {
                and: [/\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|md|mdx)$/],
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
                    {
                      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                
                plugins: [
                  isEnvDevelopment &&
                    shouldUseReactRefresh &&
                    require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
                ].filter(Boolean),
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                
                // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
                // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
                // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: [
                cssModuleRegex,
                /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
              ],
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                modules: {
                  mode: 'icss',
                },
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              exclude: [
                /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
              ],
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                modules: {
                  mode: 'local',
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: 'icss',
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: 'local',
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            // Custom loaders for CKEditor5
            {
              test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
              use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            {
              test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
              use: [
                  {
                      loader: 'style-loader',
                      options: {
                          injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                          attributes: {
                              'data-cke': true
                          }
                      }
                  },
                  'css-loader',
                  {
                      loader: 'postcss-loader',
                      options: {
                          postcssOptions: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                              themeImporter: {
                                  themePath: require.resolve( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark' )
                              },
                              minify: true
                          } )
                      }
                  }
              ]
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/^$/, /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        }
      ].filter(Boolean),
```